# Location tracking in low signal locations

Tags: java, android, android-location, android-gps

I have an app where I am trying to get users location, I need fairly accurate location tracking for my app, I have specified Criteria as High Accuracy and High Power, but at low signal places ( where both network and GPS are low in signal strength, mostly indoors ) the location tracked are like around 100 meters or more away from original location, is there any way to make it a bit more accurate ?

Comment: Unless you are ready to calculate a more accurate position depending on the last precise position (lat/long/speed/bearing). This is an hardware issues. (Also, indoor, you can have Wifi location.)

Comment: @AxelH WIFI can't be used , yes I sure want to do calculations to get more precise location , any pointer in this directions ?

Comment: Sorry, just a crazy idea actually. I guess you could use the bearing and the speed to find an approximative point, at which you need to add a radius of error. But if the user turn around... But I guess you could search for the logic a GPS software is managing the virtual position in a tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no software way to make it more accurate. Hardware ways include bluetooth beacons (you must install them on site), gathering more data about available WiFi networks to make better LBS (you have to gather ore data, than google and process it better than them) or launching new generation of GPS satellites with much more powerful transmitters (which is planned, but not done yet).